# How do i uninstall "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" via the command line

Tags: windows, networking, network-share

I would like to know how to uninstall the "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" via the command line, this is a task i will be automating so using the UI is not an option.

Unfortunately my searches have only shown me how to do this via the UI or an out of date (Win XP) method.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/526dc18f-be15-46b7-98a4-7d7878068f28/how-to-enable-file-and-printer-sharing-for-microsoft-networks-checkbox-with-powershell-script?forum=winserverpowershell

So i would appreciate it if you could provide a guide to doing this for Windows Server 2008 or Above and Windows 7 or Above?

thanks

Comment: Do you really need to "uninstall" it? Won't disabling do it?

Comment: @Lenniey i suppose disabling it would be suitable.  Although i would like to remove the related files is possible without breaking Windows, but that is out of the scope of this question :)

Comment: You could do it via GPO/local policy, but I assume you don't want that. Also you could block the necessary ports via Windows firewall, but I assume you don't want that either. Or via registry, or something. I'm not aware of a command line command for it, I'm afraid.

Comment: So lacking an uninstall method, disabling via GPO/Local Policy/Regedit script seems like a viable option.  GPO for domain joined and Regedit for Workgroup PC's given i don't know how to script local policy

Answer (score 1):

I found the tool they didn't really develop anymore (I thought), but now they re-released it for Hyper-V:

[nvspbind](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850)

This command line tool is (I think) exactly what you need.

Simply get your NICs and their open services / bindings via `nvspbind` and disable - for example file and printer sharing - via the command line switch `/d`.

In my example this would be:

```
.\nvspbind.exe /d {B4018946-5E6B-4C83-8118-97C2FD8BE90C} ms_server

acquiring write lock...success


Adapters:

{B4018946-5E6B-4C83-8118-97C2FD8BE90C}
"pci\ven_8086&dev_153b"
"Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V"
"Ethernet":
    unbinding ms_server from Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
    unbinding ms_server from Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
    unbinding ms_server from Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
    unbinding ms_server from Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V

applying changes...

cleaning up...releasing write lock...success
finished (0)
```

Applied settings:

```
.\nvspbind.exe

[...]
{B4018946-5E6B-4C83-8118-97C2FD8BE90C}
"pci\ven_8086&dev_153b"
"Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V"
"Ethernet":
   enabled:  ms_lldp          (Microsoft-LLDP-Treiber)
   enabled:  ms_netbt         (WINS Client(TCP/IP) Protocol)
   enabled:  ms_netbios       (NetBIOS Interface)
   enabled:  insecure_npcap   (Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP))
   disabled: ms_implat        (Microsoft-Multiplexorprotokoll f³r Netzwerkadapter)
   enabled:  ms_rdma_ndk      (Microsoft RDMA - NDK)
   enabled:  ms_tcpip         (Internetprotokoll, Version 4 (TCP/IPv4))
   enabled:  ms_msclient      (Client f³r Microsoft-Netzwerke)
   disabled: ms_server        (Datei- und Druckerfreigabe f³r Microsoft-Netzwerke)
[...]
```

Reenable the setting:

```
.\nvspbind.exe /e {B4018946-5E6B-4C83-8118-97C2FD8BE90C} ms_server

Hyper-V Network VSP Bind Application 6.1.7725.0.
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

acquiring write lock...success


Adapters:

{B4018946-5E6B-4C83-8118-97C2FD8BE90C}
"pci\ven_8086&dev_153b"
"Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V"
"Ethernet":
    binding ms_server to Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
    binding ms_server to Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
    binding ms_server to Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
    binding ms_server to Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V

applying changes...

cleaning up...releasing write lock...success
finished (0)
```

---

For GPO:

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Network
>   Connections > Windows Firewall > [profile] > "Windows Firewall: Allow
>   file and printer sharing exception" > Disable [+ maybe some
>   exceptions]

For command line firewall:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=No
```

This setting depends on the localization of your Windows installation.

For registry, this is somewhat...stupid:

Check the following command `wmic nicconfig get description,settingid`
In this list you'll find all your NICs and their corresponding GUID/SettingID.

For example: `Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V {B4018946-5E6B-4C83-8118-97C2FD8BE90C}`

Now in Regedit locate this key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Linkage`
There you'll find the Settings `Bind` `Export` and `Route`.
Edit the `Bind` setting, locate the GUID of your NIC you want to disable File and Print Sharing for and delete these lines. I think this approach is quite error prone.